# How to get input value to update database within PHP code

Tags: php

I'm trying to update the database via the transaction_id to make the transaction "done". I'm wondering how I can do this how I am currently setting it up. It's basically a form that is set up -- if it's not complete, the owner will have an option to update the database to complete it. If it is complete, then the transaction will indicate that it is completed. Is there a way to place the transaction ID in my input field so that I can update my database? If not, is there another I can do this? My function is as follows:

```
function finish($id){
    global $db;
    $query = "
    UPDATE `transactions`
    SET done = 'done'
    WHERE id = :id";
    $statement = $db->prepare($query);
    $statement->bindValue(':id', $id);
    $statement->execute();
    $statement->closeCursor();
}

<?php if ($transaction['done'] === NULL) {
                echo '<td>
                <form action=/activeclean/index.php?action=finish>
                    <button type="submit">FINISH</button>
                </form>
                </td>';
            } else {
    echo '<td>done</td>';
}?>
```

Comment: Something like `<input type="hidden" value="{$transaction['id']}" name="id">`?

Comment: I just tried this and unfortunately it did not work.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You have to concatenate your string.

```
'<td>
  <form action="/activeclean2/index.php?action=finish" method=POST>
    <input type="hidden" value=' . $transaction['id'] . ' name="id">
      <button type="submit">FINISH</button>
  </form>
 </td>';
```

Comment: Self answers are great, but they need enough context and explanation to be useful to other people who find the question in their search results.

Answer (score 0):

Request your all element which you want to update use `$_POST['your variable name']`.

```php
<?php
function finish($id)
{
    $id = $id;
    global $db;
    $query = "UPDATE `transactions` SET done = 'done' WHERE id = :id";
    $statement = $db->prepare($query);
    $statement->bindValue(':id', $id);
    $statement->execute();
    $statement->closeCursor();
}

if ($transaction['done'] === null) {
    echo '<td>
                <form  method="post" action="finish($id)">
                    <button type="submit">FINISH</button>
                </form>
                </td>';
} else {
    echo '<td>done</td>';
}
```

Comment: if you have enough reputation, next time like this.. just write it in a comment.

Comment: check this solution i am edited and one thing i want to ask can u get the id from the transaction completed